# How can I write a popup over edit button in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have to write a popup with input text field to be filled inorder to edit the username.When I click the edit button,a popup should be appear with input text field to enter data.The username has to be modified to data whatever I have entered in the input field.How can I implement this by using bootstrap popups in angularjs?

Comment: Please post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite straightforward to create a popup using angular bootstrap.

Read the documentation. [Angular Bootstrap Modal Directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal)

Below is a simple implementation.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ["ui.bootstrap"]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.enteredUser = {};
  $scope.enteredUser.name = 'not yet entered';
  $scope.enteredUser.address = 'not yet entered';
    
    $scope.OpenModal = function(){
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        size: "lg",
        controller: 'modalController'
      });
  
      modalInstance.result.then(function (user) {
        //$ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
        $scope.enteredUser = user;
      }, function () {
        //$log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
      });
    };
});

app.controller('modalController', function($scope, $uibModalInstance){
  $scope.ok = function(){
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.user);
  };
  
  $scope.cancel = function(){
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <div class="col-sm-12">       
      <br>
      <button class="btn" ng-click="OpenModal()">Enter User Details</button>
      <br><br>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item active">User Details</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Name: {{enteredUser.name}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Address: {{enteredUser.address}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Example input">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" ng-model="user.address" placeholder="Another input">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </script>
    
  </body>

</html>
```